# Yii2 Pjax and GridView - refresh is not working properly

Tags: yii, yii2

I am using the Pjax and GridView, and trying to make it work properly after the status of the item is changed. Currently, after the action is over, and server sends back the result, the whole **GridView** will be replaced with the text (response from the controller).

The **Pjax** code:

```
<?php
    Pjax::begin(['id' => 'product-manage']);
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $productsProvider,
        'filterModel'  => $filterModel,
        'filterPosition' => 'header',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ....
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'header' => 'Actions',
                'buttons' => [
                    ....
                    'toggle-publish' => function ($url, $model) {
                        $html = $model->published ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>';
                        return Html::a($html, $url, [
                            'title' => $model->published ? 'Unpublish' : 'Publish',
                            'data-pjax' => 'product-manage',
                            'data' => [
                                'confirm' => $model->published ? 'Are you sure you want to unpublish ' . $model->inci . ' ?' : 'Are you sure you want to publish ' . $model->inci . ' ?',
                                'method' => 'post',
                            ],
                        ]);
                    },
                ],
                'template' => '<span class="block text-center">{view}</span>
                    <span class="block text-center">{update}</span>
                    <span class="block text-center">{toggle-default-product}</span>
                    <span class="block text-center">{toggle-publish}</span>'
            ],
        ],

    ]);
    Pjax::end();
?>
```

Controller:

```
     $response = Yii::$app->response;
     $response->format     = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     $response->statusCode = 200;
     $response->data       = Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('/partials/_alerts', [
            'message' => $message,
            'type'    => 'success'
]);

   return $response;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: umm you are trying to override the `GridView` to show new updated grid results ?

Comment: you should add complete code, for example, the action from which you are opening your `GridView` and the complete code for the action that you are using for updating the status if it is different. currently the complete text is replaced with the status response text and you want to reload the gridview ? is it